# How to read a specific column from csv?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm relatively new to python.
I want to read a specific column from a csv file using the column name as my search data. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import sys

print "What column are you searching for? "
userinput = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip();

with open("my.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = reader.next()
    try:
        pos = header.index(userinput)
        print "Values in column " + userinput + ": "
        for row in reader:
            print row[pos]
    except:
        print "column not found."
```